# In Gradle, how can I find out what artifact is downgrading a version in a dependency tree?

Tags: gradle

Gradle v3.4.1

I have the following when I run a dependency tree

```
+--- project :zift-core
| ....
|    +--- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:4.0.1 -> 3.6.8
```

I even have this in my `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.hazelcast:hazelcast:4.0.1") {
      force = true
    }
}
```

How can I find out what artifact is downgrading the version to 3.6.8? Or how I can I force `hazelcast:4.0.1`?

Thanks